# Non-topological solitons in condensed matter physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, field-theory, solitons

As I know most well-known soliton solutions in condensed matter physics are topological ones: kinks, domain walls etc. 
In field theory there are several examples on non-topological solitons: Q-balls, oscillons (as long-lived excitations), chiral solitons.
Also I know about soliton explanation of Bose-Einstein condensation.

But what are examples of non-topological solitons in condensed matter physics except Bose-Einstein condensation?

It would be interesting if you can advise me some material or links about new results in this field.

Remark: I am interested in theoretical material.